# What data goes into a message between distributed applications?

Tags: queue, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, distributed-system

I am trying to implement queues into our microservice architecture, to be specific AWS SNS/SQS.

For example I have this scenarion.
After order is created Orders MS raises OrderCreated event and this event publishes message to AWS OrderCreated SNS. SQS queue InvoiceCreate is subscribed to OrderCreated SNS and will get this message.

Evertyhing makes scence so far. If Invoicing MS is listening to InvoiceCreate queueu and retrieves all new messages - Invoicing MS should create an invoice, but my question is with what data?

a) contact Order MS (to order data relevant for creating invoice). If unable to do so, message will be left in queue until Invoicing MS is able to collect the relevant data

b) message published should contain all the relevant data needed to create an invoice.

If choosing A Invoicing MS will not be decoupled and it will be depending on Order MS, but on the other hand it can collect additional data other then the data packed with original message.

If choosing B, since OrderCreated event and OrderCreated SNS doesnt really know who will use message data ie. OrderCreated could be also used to perform different actions, I am confused how to preciselly decide what data should be stuffed in this message

Answer (score 1):

Our architecture is set up more like your option B.  To use your example, the Order service would publish it's OrderCreated event and attach - as a payload - most (or even all) of the Order information in the Payload section of the message.  We format message and payload as JSON for compatibility, but you can do whatever.

In some cases, we don't publish all info, just specific fields for the Added/Edited entity - it depends on the service and the sensitivity of the information.  So long as you only ever add fields to a message (don't remove any), you are honoring the contract and aren't really tightly coupled to it.

Again, to your example, the InvoiceService could get its information from one or more of several options:

- Pull it directly from the OrderCreated message if you include everything needed
- Pull what it can from the OrderCreated message, publish an InvoiceStarted event that triggers the OrderService (and/or others) to send it an OrderInvoiceComplete message with the rest of the details it needs
- Keep a local copy of whatever key data it needs - populated by subscribing to other events - so that it can combine OrderCreated data with some local data to flesh out an invoice

It's best to avoid the InvoiceService responding to a message by making a call directly back to the OrderService - this is a pretty tight coupling that can be avoided by simply messaging back if you have to.

So, there are lots of options.  I personally prefer the technique of putting all data that might be useful into the messages when things are created/updated and letting consuming services decide what to use/ignore.  For our scenario, that works well but we have only a few well-contained clients accessing our services so there may be more secure ways to do it that aren't relevant for us.